# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression c#

Tags: c#, access-database-engine

Can some one please help me to resolve the issue ?

I am getting the syntax error while running this code.

```
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=J:\CADFileLogger.accdb");
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO [tbl_Logger] (Username,FullFileName,DateOfAction,EventMode,ShortFileName) VALUES (@a,@b,@c,@d,@e)";

cn.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, cn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@a", OleDbType.WChar).Value = username;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@b", OleDbType.WChar).Value = fullfilename;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@c ", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = now;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@d ", OleDbType.WChar).Value = mode;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@e ", OleDbType.WChar).Value = filename;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cn.Close();
```

Comment: Could it be that `Username` is a reserved word or function? I'm just guessing really.

Comment: This is a great example of where the *precise* error details - and the fact that it was a compilation error rather than an exception - would have been useful to include in the question. It's entirely feasible for *SQL* to have a syntax error, but knowing that it was a *compilation* error would have ruled that out as being the immediate problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the backslash in the data source:

```
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=J:\CADFileLogger.accdb");
```

Either put an `@` in front of the connection string or escape the backspace:

```
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=J:\CADFileLogger.accdb");
```